# Kafka-Spark Batch Streaming: WARN clients.NetworkClient: Bootstrap broker disconnected

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, jaas, sasl

I am trying to write the rows of a `Dataframe` into a `Kafka topic`. The kafka cluster is Kerberized and I am providing the jaas.conf in the --conf arguments to be able to authenticate and connect to the cluster. Below is my code:

```
object app {
  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Kerberos kafka ")
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
  System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", "path to jaas.conf")
  spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      val test= spark.sql("select * from testing.test")
      test.show()
      println("publishing to kafka...")
      val test_final = test.selectExpr("cast(to_json(struct(*)) as string) AS value")
      test_final .show()
       test_final.write.format("kafka")
          .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers","XXXXXXXXX:9093")
          .option("topic", "test")
          .option("security.protocol", "SASL_SSL")
          .option("sasl.kerberos.service.name","kafka")
          .save()

  }
}
```

When I run the above code, it fails with this error: 
`org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.`

When I looked into the error logs on executors, I see this:

```
18/08/20 22:06:05 INFO producer.ProducerConfig: ProducerConfig values: 
    compression.type = none
    metric.reporters = []
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metadata.fetch.timeout.ms = 60000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    bootstrap.servers = [xxxxxxxxx:9093]
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    buffer.memory = 33554432
    timeout.ms = 30000
    key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    block.on.buffer.full = false
    ssl.key.password = null
    max.block.ms = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    client.id = 
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    acks = 1
    batch.size = 16384
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    **security.protocol = PLAINTEXT**
    retries = 0
    max.request.size = 1048576
    value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    linger.ms = 0

18/08/20 22:06:05 **INFO utils.AppInfoParser: Kafka version : 0.9.0-kafka-2.0.2**
18/08/20 22:06:05 INFO utils.AppInfoParser: Kafka commitId : unknown
18/08/20 22:06:05 INFO datasources.FileScanRDD: Reading File path: hdfs://nameservice1/user/test5/dt=2017-08-04/5a8bb121-3cab-4bed-a32b-9d0fae4a4e8b.parquet, range: 0-142192, partition values: [2017-08-04]
18/08/20 22:06:05 INFO broadcast.TorrentBroadcast: Started reading broadcast variable 4
18/08/20 22:06:05 INFO memory.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_4_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 33.9 KB, free 5.2 GB)
18/08/20 22:06:05 INFO broadcast.TorrentBroadcast: Reading broadcast variable 4 took 224 ms
18/08/20 22:06:05 INFO memory.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_4 stored as values in memory (estimated size 472.2 KB, free 5.2 GB)
18/08/20 22:06:06 WARN clients.NetworkClient: Bootstrap broker xxxxxxxxx:9093:9093 disconnected
18/08/20 22:06:06 WARN clients.NetworkClient: Bootstrap broker xxxxxxxxx:9093:9093 disconnected
18/08/20 22:06:07 WARN clients.NetworkClient: Bootstrap broker xxxxxxxxx:9093:9093 disconnected
18/08/20 22:06:07 WARN clients.NetworkClient: Bootstrap broker xxxxxxxxx:9093:9093 disconnected
18/08/20 22:06:07 WARN clients.NetworkClient: Bootstrap broker xxxxxxxxx:9093:9093 disconnected
18/08/20 22:06:08 INFO executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Got assigned task 4
18/08/20 22:06:08 INFO executor.Executor: Running task 1.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 4)
18/08/20 22:06:08 WARN clients.NetworkClient: Bootstrap broker xxxxxxxxx:9093:9093 disconnected
18/08/20 22:06:08 INFO datasources.FileScanRDD: Reading File path: hdfs://nameservice1/user/test5/dt=2017-08-10/2175e5d9-e969-41e9-8aa2-f329b5df06bf.parquet, range: 0-77484, partition values: [2017-08-10]
18/08/20 22:06:08 WARN clients.NetworkClient: Bootstrap broker xxxxxxxxx:9093:9093 disconnected
18/08/20 22:06:09 WARN clients.NetworkClient: Bootstrap broker xxxxxxxxx:9093:9093 disconnected
18/08/20 22:06:09 WARN clients.NetworkClient: Bootstrap broker xxxxxxxxx:9093:9093 disconnected
18/08/20 22:06:10 WARN clients.NetworkClient: Bootstrap broker xxxxxxxxx:9093:9093 disconnected
18/08/20 22:06:10 WARN clients.NetworkClient: Bootstrap broker xxxxxxxxx:9093:9093 disconnected
```

In this above log, I see three entries that are conflicting:

**security.protocol = PLAINTEXT**

**sasl.kerberos.service.name = null**

**INFO utils.AppInfoParser: Kafka version : 0.9.0-kafka-2.0.2**

I am setting the `security.protocol` and `sasl.kerberos.service.name` values in my `test_final.write....`. Does that mean the configs are not being passed? The Kafka dependency I am using in my jar is:

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
      <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>0.10.2.1</version>
  </dependency>
```

Does the `0.10.2.1` version conflict with the `0.9.0-kafka-2.0.2` ? and could this be causing the issue?

Here is my jaas.conf:

```
/* $Id$ */

kinit {
 com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required;
};

KafkaClient {
 com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
 doNotPrompt=true
 useTicketCache=true
 useKeyTab=true
 principal="user@CORP.COM"
 serviceName="kafka"
 keyTab="/data/home/keytabs/user.keytab"
 client=true;
};
```

Here is my spark-submit command:

```
spark2-submit --master yarn --class app --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=path to jaas.conf"  --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=path to jaas.conf" --files path to jaas.conf --conf "spark.driver.extraClassPath=path to spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.2.0.jar"  --conf "spark.executor.extraClassPath=path to spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.2.0.jar" --num-executors 2 --executor-cores 4 --executor-memory 10g --driver-memory 5g ./KerberizedKafkaConnect-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, I am also getting same error.. can you please tell how did you resolve the issue

Comment: Unfortunately, I’ve not been able to solve it. @BigD

Comment: same problem here

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely sure if this will fix your specific issue, but in [spark structured streaming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#kafka-specific-configurations), the security options must be prefixed with `kafka.`

So you will have the following:

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.CommonClientConfigs
import org.apache.kafka.common.config.SslConfigs    

val security = Map(
  CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG -> security.securityProtocol,
  SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG -> security.sslTrustStoreLocation,
  SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG -> security.sslTrustStorePassword,
  SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG -> security.sslKeyStoreLocation,
  SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG -> security.sslKeyStorePassword,
  SslConfigs.SSL_KEY_PASSWORD_CONFIG -> security.sslKeyPassword
).map(x => "kafka." + x._1 -> x._2)

test_final.write.format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers","XXXXXXXXX:9093")
      .option("topic", "test")
      .options(security)
      .save()
```